# Not able to copy a file to a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am copying a .jpg file to other directory(C:\myFaceApp\dropbox\exprtedFaces)

My source File : C:/myFaceApp/dropbox/faces/Monika1/1404039d-2be3-43bc-b20b-35c0f4a5954b/1404039d-2be3-43bc-b20b-35c0f4a5954b_00-00-04_crop.jpg

I am using following block of code to copy

```
targetPath=opts.exportDir; //C:\myFaceApp\dropbox\exprtedFaces

fs.createReadStream(req.query.facePath).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(targetPath));
res.write(JSON.stringify({ OK: 1 }));   
res.end();
```

I am getting an error like this:

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\myFaceApp\dropbox\exprtedFaces'

Comment: You should copy code in question not send a image

Comment: Error `EISDIR` says: This path is not a file, but a directory.

Comment: You are also can use fs.copyFile https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are attempting to write to a directory not a file. `createWriteStream` takes a filename as it's argument. Try this instead:

```
fs.createReadStream(req.query.facePath).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(targetPath ,"file.jpg")));
```

You should ofc give it a non hard coded name, this is just an example. Have a look at the path module for that.

Comment: But i did a same thing with a video file, that works file for me

Comment: I don't know about what you have done before as it is not part of the question, but this is how `createWriteStream` works.

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: If it helped solve your problem please considder accepting this answer.